# Hydro ROS installed from binaries and TurtleBOT installed from source

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone,
I installed my hydro ROS from binaries and I need to install the Turtlebot from source (to access the source code for multiple turtlebot application)
Can Turtlebot from source installation run properly with hydro ROS from binaries, Debs installation? Do I have to install both from source ?
Thank you for any help in this matter.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/157141/hydro-ros-installed-from-binaries-and-turtlebot-installed-from-source/) by [Robert1](https://answers.ros.org/users/12391/robert1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2014-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, should be no problem mixing the two. And if there is, then the turtlebot sources need to be patched, updated and re-released.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2014-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robert1](https://answers.ros.org/users/12391/robert1/) on 2014-04-28**:
Thanks Daniel for your feedback!